# How to Write a Trigger when you insert or update a Contact, its Parent account's description should be populated into the contact description?

Tags: apex, trigger, salesforcedx, apexrest

I need to write a trigger for the following operation: when you insert or update a contact, its parent account's description should be populated into the contact description. I am unable to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will not write the code but I will guide you steps-

1- Traverse on new list and create a set of accountId(con.AccountId).

2-Query all the account where Id In set and create a map of Map<Id,String>accountIdToDescriptionMap.

3- Now traverse newlist again and based on step 2 map get description of parent account and populate in child.

Perform this in before insert and before update so there will be no dml. Write the code and if you face any error you can ask.

Comment: In the third step if we iterate over Trigger.new again we cant ensure that specific contact will get that specific parent account's description. Should I iterate over contact list like this where con.AccountId IN: accountIdToDescriptionMap.keyset() and then inside the iteration update each contact description to map.get(contact.AccountId)?

Comment: In third step you can get specific accountId.

**for(Contact con: newlist){
        con.Description = map.containsKey(con.AccountId)?map.get(con.AccountId):'';
}**

Comment: Thanks it works. What is the best way to approach such scenarios? I mean for interviews. I mean should we go step by step to fetch the ID of accounts first then based on those IDs we get our account records and then create a map and do processing once we have our required data?

Comment: Yes, this is optimized and best approach for questions like this. Also mention before trigger as well. So that there will be no extra dml.

Glad it helps you,  kindly upvote it as well.